# What's the difference between :focus:required:invalid:focus and :focus:required:invalid?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've been trying to work AngularJS' email validation with Bootstrap's form styling and came across this block of CSS.

```
input:focus:required:invalid,
textarea:focus:required:invalid,
select:focus:required:invalid {
  color: #b94a48;
  border-color: #ee5f5b;
}

input:focus:required:invalid:focus,
textarea:focus:required:invalid:focus,
select:focus:required:invalid:focus {
  border-color: #e9322d;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
          box-shadow: 0 0 6px #f8b9b7;
}
```

I noticed the second :focus gave it higher priority, but I can't help but think there's more to it than that?

Thanks

Comment: This file is generated by LESS. It [looks like](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/62c78e46f8d027d0797c66bef5ce8cdb8d667ace#diff-3) the duplicate :focus is a blunder that happened in a refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the spec says about [calculating specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity):

> A selector's specificity is calculated as follows:
>
> - count the number of ID selectors in the selector (= a)
> - count the number of class selectors, attributes selectors, and pseudo-classes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of type selectors and pseudo-elements in the selector (= c)
> - ignore the universal selector
>
> Selectors inside the negation pseudo-class are counted like any other,
>   but the negation itself does not count as a pseudo-class.
>
> Concatenating the three numbers a-b-c (in a number system with a large
>   base) gives the specificity.
>
> **Note: Repeated occurrences of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity.**

There's nothing written about uniqueness, so writing the pseudo-class twice does make the selector more specific, just like [`p.foo.foo` is more specific than `p.foo`](http://jsfiddle.net/aUwJb/), yet it matches the exact same elements.

Comment: The emphasis seems misplaced. I think you meant to emphasize the note about repeated simple selectors.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks. For some reason I thought "simple selector" excluded pseudo-classes.

Comment: Nope... but it does exclude pseudo-elements!